# Why is docker 4 times slower on the first run?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, blender

Triggered from a S3.NewlyCreatedObject lambda function (python), the first `docker run` is approx. 4 times slower. Any ideas how to circumvent that?

```sh
docker build --tag=blender30 ./Dockerfile
docker run -v /tmp/:/tmp/ blender30 echo "hello from the blender docker container"

# Benchmark starts here:
docker run -e PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 -v /tmp/:/tmp/ blender30 \
       blender --background /tmp/input.blend --python /tmp/mylogger.py \
       --debug \
       --debug-all | tee /tmp/blender.log ;\

# 1. 160 seconds
# 2. 40 seconds
# 3. 40 seconds
```

---

Edit:

I just stumbled over [lambda provisioned-concurrency](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/). Is that the cause?

Dockerfile:

```sh
# Dockerfile autogenerated on 06/09/2021, 09:43:33 by juniorxsound 
# Please do not edit this file directly 

FROM ubuntu:18.04

LABEL Title="Blender in Docker"

# Enviorment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV PATH "$PATH:/bin/2.80/python/bin/"
ENV BLENDER_PATH "/bin/2.80"
ENV BLENDERPIP "/bin/2.80/python/bin/pip3"
ENV BLENDERPY "/bin/2.80/python/bin/python3.7m"
ENV HW="CPU"

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \ 
    wget \ 
    libopenexr-dev \ 
    bzip2 \ 
    build-essential \ 
    zlib1g-dev \ 
    libxmu-dev \ 
    libxi-dev \ 
    libxxf86vm-dev \ 
    libfontconfig1 \ 
    libxrender1 \ 
    libgl1-mesa-glx

# Download and install Blender
RUN wget https://mirror.clarkson.edu/blender/release/Blender2.80/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2 \ 
    && tar -xjvf blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2 --strip-components=1 -C /bin \ 
    && rm -rf blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64.tar.bz2 \ 
    && rm -rf blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64 

# Download the Python source since it is not bundled with Blender
RUN wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && tar -xzf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && cp -r Python-3.7.0/Include/* $BLENDER_PATH/python/include/python3.7m/ \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0.tgz \ 
    && rm -rf Python-3.7.0 

# Blender comes with a super outdated version of numpy (which is needed for matplotlib / opencv) so override it with a modern one
RUN rm -rf ${BLENDER_PATH}/python/lib/python3.7m/site-packages/numpy 

# Must first ensurepip to install Blender pip3 and then new numpy
RUN ${BLENDERPY} -m ensurepip && ${BLENDERPIP} install --upgrade pip && ${BLENDERPIP} install numpy

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /
```

Comment: Maybe you can share the `.Dockerfile`

Comment: Without knowing what's in that `blender30` image it's hard to tell.  Have you added any instrumentation to your application to tell where it's going slowly?